# SSRS - Textbox Linebreak (or) Linking Table w/ Textbox

Tags: reporting-services, line-breaks, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

My SSRS report contains 4 tables, all of which have line breaks at the bottom.

I'm trying to find a way to tie my text boxes (titles for each table) to only show up on the first page of the start of each table. I'm honestly at a loss for this particular issue.

--Unrelated --
Originally I had a parameter with a visibility expression and a toggle option to switch between each table, but due to a recent change request the entire report needs to be on one screen.

```
(=IIF(Parameters!SelectAScreen.Value = "InvoiceDetails",false,true))
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a row at the top of each table for the titles?

Comment: No I haven't. That should work though! It may not look as aesthetically pleasing, but it's good in my book. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think if you add an extra row above your data (**outside** the group) and set the **RepeatOnNewPage** to **False**, it should work the way you want it too.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some version of @StevenWhite's comment above is the only way I know to do this.  One way to do it is to do a union with a dummy key to force the title row to the top of each table:

```
select 1 as dummyKey,
       'Title text for table1'
union all
select 2 as dummyKey,
       <columns> from <table1>
 order by dummyKey, <other sort columns>
```

and repeat for each table's dataset.

If necessary you can also do conditional formatting to make the title row stand out and look like a title.